# Transfer mysql to access including relationships and foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, mysql-workbench, er-diagram

Is it possible to convert My ER diagram/database from MYSQL WORKBENCH to MS ACCESS?

Will it include all the tables with their relationships to each other?

(foreign keys, data types one to many designations etc. ?)

Comment: mysql workbench is the name of a software used to access the database mysql. you are trying to transfer from mysql to ms access. workbench is the tool you used to use and is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this for information on transferring from mysql to ms access.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-import.html

These tools generally copy all table constraints as well.